Is there a way to limit what causes an installable trigger to run?
Is it possible to add nuance to an installable trigger? I have a function that is linked to an installable trigger (onEdit). The purpose of this script is to remove editors of cells with certain color backgrounds. Ideally, this protectColor installable trigger would only run when someone edits a the value in column 4, but not when there are other changes to the spreadsheet. I've included the code I'm using currently.
function protectColor() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('newRow')
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
      var backgrounds = sheet.getRange(1,1,1000,18).getBackgrounds(); 
      for (let i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++) { // Loop through rows in sheet
        for (let j = 0; j < backgrounds[i].length; j++) { // Loop through current row
         if (backgrounds[i][j] === "#d9e2f3") { // Change if necessary
            var blueCell = sheet.getRange(i+1, j+1); // Get blue cell
            var protection = blueCell.protect(); // Protect cell
            var me = 'fake@fake.org';
           protection.addEditor(me);
            protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
            if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
              protection.setDomainEdit(false);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  
}

The reason I am using an installable trigger here is because users need to be able to use a different function, that is assigned to a button (newFormulaRow), to insert new formula rows BUT I don't want them to be able to edit the formulas. Sadly I can't remove editors in the newFormulaRow script, which makes logical sense but is annoying.
I've tried to use activeRange to limit what triggers this script, but haven't had any luck.

Try using e.range.columnStart == 4

In  answer to your question, no. But you can control how the handler function behaves when the trigger is fired.

There is no way to limit when a trigger gets activated but you make your make use of control flow statements like if and conditional expressions.
Tip
Create trigger handler function calls the function that do the changes that you want to limit using a if statement.
function respondToOnEdit(e){
  if(
     e.range.columnStart === 4
     && e.value !== undefined // value property only is included when a single cell is edited
  ) protectColor(e);
  // If the conditional expression returns false, then do nothing
}

Set your installable on edit trigger to call respondToOnEdit instead of protectColor.
Notes:
The above do nothing when

A cell is cleared.
Multiple cells are edited at once, i.e., by paste of a range, or to multiple selected cells.

I don't know if that is relevant your use case.
